# Pandas interpolate keep original index

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I am doing some pandas interpolation in a series in which the index is not continuous. So it can be something like this:

```
     Value   Customer_id
0.    5          A
1.    np.nan     A
10.   9          A
11.   10         B
12.   np.nan     B
13.   30         B
```

I'm interpolating taking into account the customer_id (in this case it makes no difference, but my dataframe has NaNs in the starting or ending point of a customer)

So I'm doing

```
    series = series.groupby('Customer_id').apply(lambda group: group.interpolate(method= interpolation_method))
```

Where interpolation_method is 'cubic' or 'index' (I'm testing both. for different purposes).

How can I do the interpolation and keep the original index somehow in a of column or in the index if possible so that I canter join with other data frames?

Comment: If the first and last value for each group is not NaN, you could bypass groupby altogether and use interoplate on the original series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own interpolation function using `np.polyfit`. Let's say you have this dataframe where customer `A` begins with `na`:

```
    Value Customer_id
0     NaN           A
1     5.0           A
10    9.0           A
11   10.0           B
12    NaN           B
13   30.0           B
```

Fill the missing values with a custom interpolation:

```
def interpolate(group):
    x = group.dropna()
    params = np.polyfit(x.index, x['Value'], deg=1)
    predicted = np.polyval(params, group.index)

    s = pd.Series(predicted, index=group.index)
    return group['Value'].combine_first(s)

df.groupby('Customer_id').apply(interpolate).to_frame().reset_index(level=0)
```

Result:

```
   Customer_id      Value
0            A   4.555556
1            A   5.000000
10           A   9.000000
11           B  10.000000
12           B  20.000000
13           B  30.000000
```

This assumes that there is a minium of 2 valid `Value` per customer.